# How do I have access to my Google Music contents offline?

Tags: iphone, music

How are you supposed to use Google Music on and iPhone? I uploaded a lot of my music to Google Music but I want to have offline access to them on my iPhone.

Comment: Even an Android phone doesn't have *offline* access to music stored in Google Music, does it?

Comment: You can have offline access on Android

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does it work? How does it know what it should and shouldn't cache locally for offline access?

Answer (score 2):

Google do not provide offline access for google music on the iPhone.

However just searching "Google music" on the App Store, shows 2 (paid) applications, that seem to offer offline access.

Answer (score 1):

Offline access won't be possible until Google either releases an iOS music app or a Google Music API. Both are very unlikely.

Have a look at [iTunes Match](http://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/) though.